# ayuda con calculadora en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy haciendo una calculadora con javascript y por alguna razon me arroja como valor NaN, me lo arroja en la segunda y tercera funcion, pero en la primera no, no encuentro el error, copie y pegue el codigo de la primera funcion y cambie los valores y no veo el error.
gracias.

```js
// Variables
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var realSerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var imaginarySerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var moduleSerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2];
var phaseSerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3];
var realSerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4];
var imaginarySerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[5];
var moduleSerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[6];
var phaseSerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[7];
var realParallelZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[8];
var imaginaryParallelZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[9];
var moduleParallelZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[10];
var phaseParallelZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[11];
var realParallelZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[12];
var imaginaryParallelZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[13];
var moduleParallelZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[14];
var phaseParallelZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[15];
var resultRealSerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[17];
var resultImaginarySerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[18];
var resultModuleSerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[19];
var resultPhaseSerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[20];
var resultRealParallel = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[21];
var resultImaginaryParallel = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[22];
var resultModuleParallel = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[23];
var resultPhaseParallel = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[24];

// Conversor de angulos
Math.degreesToRadians = function(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
  };
Math.radiansToDegrees = function(radians) {
    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
};

// Calculadora
var sumSerie = function(){
    var realSerie = realSerieZ1.valueAsNumber + realSerieZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var imaginarySerie = imaginarySerieZ1.valueAsNumber + imaginarySerieZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var totalSerie = Math.hypot(realSerie,imaginarySerie);
    var sinSerie = imaginarySerie / totalSerie;
    var phaseRadSerie = Math.asin(sinSerie);
    var phaseDegSerie = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRadSerie);
    resultPhaseSerie.valueAsNumber = phaseDegSerie.toFixed(2);
    resultModuleSerie.valueAsNumber = totalSerie.toFixed(2);
}
var moduleAndPhaseZ1 = function(){
    var module1 = Math.hypot(realSerieZ1,imaginarySerieZ1);
    var sin = imaginarySerieZ1 / module1;
    var phaseRad = Math.asin(sin);
    var phaseDeg = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad);
    phaseSerieZ1.valueAsNumber = phaseDeg.toFixed(2);
    moduleSerieZ1.valueAsNumber = module1.toFixed(2);
}
var sumParallel = function(){
    var denominatorReal = realParallelZ1.valueAsNumber + realParallelZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var denominatorImaginary = imaginaryParallelZ1.valueAsNumber + imaginaryParallelZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var denominatorModule = Math.hypot(denominatorReal,denominatorImaginary);
    var denominatorSin = denominatorImaginary / denominatorModule;
    var denominatorPhaseRad = Math.asin(denominatorSin);
    var denominatorPhaseDeg = Math.radiansToDegrees(denominatorPhaseRad);
    var module1 = Math.hypot(realParallelZ1,imaginaryParallelZ1);
    var sin1 = imaginaryParallelZ1 / module1;
    var phaseRad1 = Math.asin(sin1);
    var phaseDeg1 = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad1);
    var module2 = Math.hypot(realParallelZ2,imaginaryParallelZ2);
    var sin2 = imaginaryParallelZ2 / module2;
    var phaseRad2 = Math.asin(sin2);
    var phaseDeg2 = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad2);
    var nominatorModule = module1 * module2;
    var nominatorPhase = phaseDeg1 + phaseDeg2;
    var totalModule = nominatorModule / denominatorModule;
    var totalPhase = nominatorPhase - denominatorPhaseDeg;
    resultModuleParallel.valueAsNumber = totalModule.toFixed(2);
    resultPhaseParallel.valueAsNumber = totalPhase.toFixed(2);
}
// button
button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sumSerie();
    moduleAndPhaseZ1();
    sumParallel();
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body{
    width: 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.serieParallel{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(10, 126, 221);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: left;
}
form input{
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 60px;
}
form p{
    display: inline;
}
form div{
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Calculadoras</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Impedancias serie y paralelo</h1>
    <div class="serieParallel">
        <form action="">
            <div>
                <h3>Suma en serie:</h3>
                <p style="display: block">Z1 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>||</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p style="display: block">Z2 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>||</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <h3>Suma en parelo:</h3>
                <p style="display: block">Z1 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>||</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p style="display: block">Z2 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>||</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="calcular" id="button">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 style="margin-bottom: 18px">Resultado:</h3>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>||</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001" style="margin-bottom: 67px">
                <h3 style="margin-bottom: 18px">Resultado:</h3>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>||</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

P.D.: lamento que el codigo sea largo, luego vere si puedo hacerlo mas corto pero por ahora lo dejo asi, asi puedo ver bien los errores

Comment: Hola! Generalmente sale por una división entre cero, revisa la consola del navegador donde te marca el error para ayudarte de manera más precisa.

Comment: linea 52,53,74 y 75

(52 y 53)
phaseSerieZ1.valueAsNumber = phaseDeg.toFixed(2);
    moduleSerieZ1.valueAsNumber = module1.toFixed(2);


(74 y 75)
resultModuleParallel.valueAsNumber = totalModule.toFixed(2);
    resultPhaseParallel.valueAsNumber = totalPhase.toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que operaste con objetos input y no con sus valores cambia tus funciones `var moduleAndPhaseZ1` y `var sumParallel` por:

```
var moduleAndPhaseZ1 = function(){
    var module1 = Math.hypot(realSerieZ1.valueAsNumber,imaginarySerieZ1.valueAsNumber);
    var sin = imaginarySerieZ1.valueAsNumber / module1;
    var phaseRad = Math.asin(sin);
    var phaseDeg = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad);
    phaseSerieZ1.valueAsNumber = phaseDeg.toFixed(2);
    moduleSerieZ1.valueAsNumber = module1.toFixed(2);
}

var sumParallel = function(){
    var denominatorReal = realParallelZ1.valueAsNumber + realParallelZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var denominatorImaginary = imaginaryParallelZ1.valueAsNumber + imaginaryParallelZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var denominatorModule = Math.hypot(denominatorReal,denominatorImaginary);
    var denominatorSin = denominatorImaginary / denominatorModule;
    var denominatorPhaseRad = Math.asin(denominatorSin);
    var denominatorPhaseDeg = Math.radiansToDegrees(denominatorPhaseRad);
    var module1 = Math.hypot(realParallelZ1.valueAsNumber,imaginaryParallelZ1.valueAsNumber);
    var sin1 = imaginaryParallelZ1.valueAsNumber / module1;
    var phaseRad1 = Math.asin(sin1);
    var phaseDeg1 = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad1);
    var module2 = Math.hypot(realParallelZ2.valueAsNumber,imaginaryParallelZ2.valueAsNumber);
    var sin2 = imaginaryParallelZ2.valueAsNumber / module2;
    var phaseRad2 = Math.asin(sin2);
    var phaseDeg2 = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad2);
    var nominatorModule = module1 * module2;
    var nominatorPhase = phaseDeg1 + phaseDeg2;
    var totalModule = nominatorModule / denominatorModule;
    var totalPhase = nominatorPhase - denominatorPhaseDeg;
    resultModuleParallel.valueAsNumber = totalModule.toFixed(2);
    resultPhaseParallel.valueAsNumber = totalPhase.toFixed(2);
}
```